# How to make Jenkins poll git upstream?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have two Git repos: A (public) and B (private), where B is a fork of A, and B needs to be synchronized with A regularly. I have also added repo A to be a remote upstream of repo B like this:

```
cd <local_folder_of_repo_B>
git remote add upstream <URL_of_repo_A>
```

I know that I can merge changes from A into B manually like this:

```
cd <local_folder_of_repo_B>
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

I have created a Jenkins job that triggers when there are commits in repo B. However, I need this job to also trigger when there are commits in repo A, too. Then merge those changes into repo B and build.

EDIT:
I have tried using the [Jenkins Multiple SCMs plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin). I added the two Git repositories and provided different local folders for them, as it is explained in the plugin page. Now the Jenkins job correctly polls both repos and triggers itself, but I am trying to avoid the need to keep two separate repos on my hard disk, because they are too large and I'm planning to scale this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider only one job which would be triggered:

- by new commits in `B` (usual Jenkins polling)
- by new commits in `A` (with `A` pushing to Jenkins a notification), with a hook on `A`, [similar to this one](https://gist.github.com/abtris/2725515):

update hook on `A`:

```
REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
curl http://jenkins.local:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@git.local/$REPOSITORY_BASENAME
```

In any case, the job would always starts fetching from `A` (`upstream`) and merging `upstream/master` to `master`, just in case.

Comment: I don't understand. What is that hook? This seems to me like shell commands. Is it some GitHub Web hook that I don't understand, or what?

Comment: @PavelTankov it is a post-update hook. And you didn't mentioned GitHub anywhere in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's true I didn't mention GitHub. I figured out that for GitHub the correct hook would be:
    http://jenkins.example.com/github-webhook/
But still, I don't see how I can configure my jenkins job. The job configuration has one Repository URL field and I can either put repo A or repo B there. In any case I still can't do the usual Jenkins polling AND the notification with a hook, as you suggest.

Comment: @PavelTankov if this is GitHub, then you need a webhook which will call a listener which, in turn, will call the script I mention.